# Change simple symbol color by expression

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS, I want to display points on a basemap, the color of the point (symbol) I need to change from a 'rule based' expression.

I have loaded a basemap, imported my data, a .csv file containing amongst others a lat column, a lon column and a 'level' column, containing values from -30 to -140.

I have selected 'rule based' and in the 'expression' I have "level" >-108.
This puts me a colored dot on the map at the correct point when the value in the 'level field is greater than -108, but what I want is for the dot to be a different color if 'level is less than -108, (there are some other fields that I will deal with later, hence needing a rules based expression).

So, basically, my question is how do I make the symbol a different color depending on the value when using expressions? I have tried color_rgb and symbol_color, neither worked.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @tsteele! Perhaps an expression like: `if("level" > -108, color_rgb(0, 255, 0), color_rgb(255, 0, 0))`

Comment: Hi Joseph, I tried that, as you wrote, but the symbol (point) didn't change color.

Comment: You don't need to use rule-based for the expression, you can use `Single symbol`, click the _Simple marker_ to open all the options. Then click the little box icon on the right of the **Fill** option and enter the expression there :)

Comment: Hi Joseph, Fabulous, doing it like hat worked, but.... I have another colums 'Channel' which is a radio channel.

Comment: Apologies, hit enter by mistake. The radio channel column has radio channels from lets say 1 - 5. Now, and this was my reason for entering the expression as rule based, if the channel is 1, the level would be -108, if the channel was 2, it would be -110 if channel was 3, the level would be -115 and so on. Can I put multiple expressions for a single point to change the color depending on the channel and the level?

Answer (score 5):

Following conversations between @tsteele and @Joseph, this is a summary of steps to set colors using both `"level"` and `"channel"` fields.

[image]

1. Start with `Rule-based` symbology. Create five groups by `"channel"` fields (`1 - 5`).
2. Double-click on `"channel"=1` group to open an edit window. Select `Simple marker` and `Data defined override` icon at the right-hand side of the `Fill color`. Select `Edit` option.
3. Enter the expression provided by @Joseph (`if("level" > -108, color_rgb(0, 255, 0), color_rgb(255, 0, 0))`). Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> to close.
4. Repeat this to `channel = 2 - 5` as well. The expression is kept in `Recent` group, so repeating it is quite easy task.

There is an option to set sub-rules (pull-down menu is shown in the above picture) but setting expression would be easy enough.